# how to change a div content to confirmation page on submit

Tags: php

Trying to change the text in the Div to a confirmation text without achanging anything on the page. I tried several example as listed on the snippet but nothing has worked so far.

[image]

> `";
>             echo "Thank you. The synonym list is added to the database.
> ";
>             echo "Would you like to add another set of synonyms?";
>             echo "";
>        }else{
>             echo "";
>             echo "Name In Synonym  Add Word Pairs
> ";
>             echo "Enter all the synonyms seperated by comma";
>             echo "";
>        }   ?>
>
> > if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
> >
> > ```
> >  $words = trim($_POST['addWord']);
> >  //echo $_POST['addWord'];
> >  if($_POST['addWord'] == ''){
> >       echo "<p class= \"fontword\">You did not enter any words. Please try again.</p>";
> >  }`
> > ```

Comment: Since you have 1 rep: Try posting what you've done so far (edit your post). Demonstrate you're working the problem versus just asking for someone to give you free code.

Comment: @WillBickford   the snippet is what I've done and I did not ask for free code. Just some suggestion if that's okay with you.

Comment: Using `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` seem to work. @WillBickford It's great that you're way ahead in the game and you know a lot but being disrespectful is not cool no matter how much knowledge you have. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Is your issue that you are getting no ajax response or is it that the submit button actually submits the page even if you have specified "preventDefault"?

Comment: getting no ajax response is the issue. @blokeish but  used `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` and an extra parameter to check the post which seems to work. But i really wanted to figure out the ajax issue since I am not familiar with it. Thanks

Comment: What's the file name of the script posted above? addWordPair.php? To me it seems that you are trying to post data to the same script. Try to split the submit form and jquery in one file (eg: enterWordPair.php) and call another php script (eg: addWordPair.php) by the ajax to add the data to the database. The second file should only have php code to validate and add the data and, echo a response. It would be great if you can post the script in jsfiddle or somewhere similar.